# How to troubleshoot integrated webcam on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: thinkpad, webcam

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 18.04
The integrated webcam was working fine...until it wasn't.

My computer suddenly stopped being able to detect the camera.
For example, when I open Cheese, there's a black screen with "No device found" written on it.

What are the troubleshooting steps I should try to figure out what's wrong and fix it?

I've tried restarting the computer.

The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 248a:8367  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for your help and ideas.